# Role of local machine when transferring between AWS and Google

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-datastore, data-transfer, cp, gsutil

I've been using Google's gsutil tool to copy files from AWS S3 to Google Cloud Store and am wondering what role (besides holding my Google credentials file) my local machine plays in this process? I am moving terabytes of data so I can't imagine that data is coming down from S3 onto my computer and then back up to Google. However, I notice the fans on my machine start whirring during the transfer and the process breaks if my computer goes to sleep, so I gather it must play some part. Can someone please enlighten me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is in fact proxied through your local machine when doing a cross-provider copy.  Gsutil refers to this as "daisy chain" mode - you can read a bit more about it by running `gsutil help cp` and referring to the summary for the `-D` option.